# Using php variables to manipulate the html's title and the body's Id (is anybody doing this?)

Tags: php, html, variables

I basically use php variables to store the value of the title and the body's ID.
This last one is a technique to have my button (pressed) in the navigation according to which section of the page the user is (in this case the user will know he is currently at "home").

Beginning of my `index.php`:

```
<?php
    $title = "New Project";
    $body = "home";
    include("common/header.php");
?>
<div id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="tagline">
```

Beginning of my header.php

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/slimbox2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/global.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/home.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/contact.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.corner.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/slimbox2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/custom.js"></script>
</head>
</head>
<body id="<?php echo $body; ?>">
<div id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="topbar">
            <h1><a href="http://widerdesign.co.nr/">wider design</a></h1>
            <ul id="lang">
                <li><a href="index.php">English</a></li>
                <li><a href="es/index.php">Español</a></li>
                <li><a href="tw/index.php">中文(繁體)</a></li>
                <li><a href="cn/index.php">中文(简体)</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="nav">
                <li class="home"><a href="index.php">home</a></li>
                <li class="products"><a href="products.php">products</a></li>
                <li class="about"><a href="about.php">about</a></li>
                <li class="contact"><a href="contact.php">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
```

To let the user know in which section he/she is:

```
#home li.home a, #products li.products a, #contact li.contact {
    color: #999;
}
```

is there a simpler way of doing this?

Am I using unnecessary those PHP variables?

Comment: I think it's ok, there is no "include with variables" - unles you use some framework.

Comment: For sanity reasons, you need to  html_entities()  on the title, just in case it includes any funny characters, in your example it's not important but if you retrieve these titles from a database or whatever, it's a way to run XSS exploits on your site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, what you're doing is fine. I do something similar with a PageTemplate class. In addition to setting the title and navigation, it allows navigation links to appear based on user authentication, allows javascript and css to be added to the head section, etc.

What you're doing is very common. There are a million ways to do it, but they'll all require setting some variables.

Answer (score 1):

janoChen,

I use the following method:

// get the url

```
$url= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

// add a class on the menu item

```
<ul id="lang">
      <li><a href="index.php" <?php if (strpos($url, "index.php")) { echo " class='active'"; } ?>>English</a></li>
```

//with css I set a style for the class active

```
li a.active { 
 color: #990000;
}
```

But you method also works.

Answer (score 0):

Or else use an MVC framework like [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)

Comment: Is it OK to use CakePHP, even if my web page is 98% static (it just display information, pictures and it has a contact form)?

Comment: If your site is that static, you don't need to use CakePHP (or any other framework for that matter), it would be just too overloaded with (for this purpose) unnecessary stuff

Answer (score -1):

This works, but you should consider using a template engine such as [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) instead.

Comment: For these purposes, PHP arguably _is_ the templating engine.  No need to add another layer on.